# Erro em tema de app

Tags: android, android-studio

Pessoal eu implementei algumas abas no app que estou desenvolvendo com fragments e tive que usar o tema da APPCompat mas começou a dar esse erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Ai vou la no manifest e troco pro AppCompat, mas ai não aparece mais a minha actionbar no app.

Com o Theme.Holo.Light a actionbar aparece, mas se troco por causa do erro ela some.

E agora?

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

---

Manifest

---

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo_bse_sem_fundo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Home_Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".BuscarClienteActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".InformacoesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></activity>
</application>
```

---

Styles

---

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: posta o teu manifest e o teu style.xml pra gente ver como tá, dai fica mais facil pra ver o que se pode fazer.

Answer (score 0):

A `Activity` que você está tentando usar a `ActionBar` estende da classe `ActionBarActivity`, neste caso é obrigatório que você utilize o tema do `AppCompat`.

Faça sua activity estender da classe `Activity` e deixe o tema `Theme.Holo.Light` que provavelmente vai funcionar.

---

**@Edit**

Se quiser continuar utilizando o `AppCompat`, utilize um tema descendente do `Theme.AppCompat`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` ou `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Então, eu resolvi isso adicionando android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" na declaração da activity no manifest. Mas por ser tema da AppCompat a actionbar muda de aparência eu queria manter a aparência da actionbar como nas outras que usam o tema Holo. Esta activity estende de AppCompatActivity. Tem como eu usar as abas sem usar a AppCompat?

Comment: Fui mudando tudo de appCompat para android.app mas meu adapter extende de FragmentStatePagerAdapter que pelo visto só existe na API de suporte. Não achei ele para android.app.